# Master page acting weird

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

So I applied this master page to two files..one inside the same folder(file1.aspx) as the master page..another outside(file2.aspx)..master page is applying alright to file2.aspx BUT not completely..a TD's bgcolor is missing..and ONLY that..why so ?

BOTH files got no code of their own yet..just the application of the master page

[Edit]

this is the address to the master page in both the files

MasterPageFile="~/templates/master1.master"

both files got no tag..nothing..just the application of this master page

Comment: Probably you miss some css or other files on master page because to path changes (and you did not take care about)

Comment: but it's only ONE TD's bgcolor that is missing..EVERYTHING else is getting applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All css links all master page resolved relative to the page location, not the master location. Is it possible that you two pages are in folders at different nesting level and you did not account for it?

Comment: Files are located like this..........

General->Docs-> File2.aspx

& 
Templates->master1.master and File1.aspx

What should be the path to th emaster page in fle2.aspx ?

Isn't this correct already ?
MasterPageFile="~/templates/master1.master"

Comment: hv sorted it out..it was some path problem